# Does Spark guarantee consistency when reading data from S3?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark Job that reads data from S3. I apply some transformations and write 2 datasets back to S3. Each write action is treated as a separate job.

Question: Does Spark guarantees that I read the data each time in the same order? For example, if I apply the function:

```
.withColumn('id', f.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Will the **id** column have the **same** **values** for the **same** **records** each time?

Comment: There is no guarantee that it would have the same Id value when you write the data. But once written, when you read it would have same ids as data is persisted to some storage.

Comment: Do not think the title and text match. Pls change it.

Comment: Is the data subject to change possibly? caching applied? same spark app?

Comment: Good question. Maybe, but if you are relying on the data being consistently ordered then why rely on the Spark implementation internals which may well change between versions? If you add an orderBy clause before adding the id won't you be guaranteed the consistent ordering you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state very little, but the following is easily testable and should serve as a guideline:

- If you re-read the same files again with same content you will get the same blocks / partitions again and the same id using `f.monotonically_increasing_id()`.
- If the total number of rows differs on the successive read(s) with different partitioning applied before this function, then typically you will get different id's.
- If you have more data second time round and apply coalesce(1) then the prior entries will have same id still, newer rows will have other ids. A less than realistic scenario of course.

Blocks for files at rest remain static (in general) on HDFS. So partition 0..N will be the same upon reading from rest. Otherwise `zipWithIndex` would not be usable either.

I would never rely on the same data being in same place when read twice unless there were no updates (you could cache as well).